# Program doesn't run, exited with code 0 and doesnt show anything

Tags: c#

Visual Studio 2019 says no issues :

> 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date

This program (with french variables/constants) is supposed to conserve data related to players of a team. It determines wether a player has the most weight out of any other team. It does this until the amount of players for each team hits 33 and until the amount of teams hit 24.

```
    const int JoueurCible = 33; 
    const int ÉquipeCible = 24;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numéroÉquipe = 0; 
        int poidsPlusLourd = 0; 
        int équipePlusLourd = 0; 
        string nomPlusLourd = "."; 
        string nomJoueur = ".";
        int âgeJoueur = 0;
        int poidsJoueur = 0;
        int âgeMoyenneÉquipe = 0; 
        int poidsMoyenneÉquipe = 0; 

        for (int i = 1; i == ÉquipeCible; ++i)
        {
            Write("Veuillez entrer les données de l'équipe " + numéroÉquipe + "." + "\n");
            numéroÉquipe += 1;

            for (int x = 1; x == JoueurCible; ++x)
            {
                Write("Veuillez entrer le nom du joueur.");
                nomJoueur = Convert.ToString(ReadLine()); 
                Write("Veuillez entrer l'âge du joueur.");
                âgeJoueur = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine()); 
                Write("Veuillez entrer le poids du joueur.");
                poidsJoueur = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine()); 

                âgeMoyenneÉquipe = âgeMoyenneÉquipe + âgeJoueur;
                poidsMoyenneÉquipe = poidsMoyenneÉquipe + poidsJoueur;

                if (poidsJoueur > poidsPlusLourd)
                {
                    poidsPlusLourd = poidsJoueur;
                    Write("Veuillez entrer le nom de ce joueur ainsi que le numéro de l'équipe" +
                    "donc il fait parti.");
                    nomPlusLourd = Convert.ToString(ReadLine());
                    équipePlusLourd = x;
                }
            }
            âgeMoyenneÉquipe = âgeMoyenneÉquipe / JoueurCible;
            poidsMoyenneÉquipe = poidsMoyenneÉquipe / JoueurCible;

            WriteLine("L'âge moyen de l'équipe est de " + âgeMoyenneÉquipe + " et le poids" +
                    " moyenne de l'équipe est de " + poidsMoyenneÉquipe + ".");
            WriteLine("Le nom du joueur le plus lourd est " + nomPlusLourd + " faisant parti de l'équipe numéro " +
            équipePlusLourd + " avec un poids de " + poidsPlusLourd + ".");
        }
   }
```

Comment: Look over your [`for` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) again, specifically the condition on which it runs...  *Hint*: If the condition is `i == ÉquipeCible`, upon first running the program, will `i` be `24`?

Comment: As @maccettura said, the for loop contains i == ÉquipeCible which means, when 
i == 24 go inside the loop, try to change to i <= 24 ... and so the same for the inner for loop. Make it x <= JoueurCible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `for` loop definition, it states that `for (int i = 1; i == ÉquipeCible; ++i)`, however, it will never execute its body because `i = 1` and `ÉquipeCible = 24`, so the condition `i == ÉquipeCible` is not met and hence the body of the loop will not be entered. Perhaps you meant `for (int i = 1; i <= ÉquipeCible; ++i)` or `for (int i = 1; i < ÉquipeCible; ++i)`.